# XCode 6.0.1 Enterprise In House Distribution Is Not Creating ipa/plist

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, enterprise

After upgrading to XCode 6.0.1, in In House Enterprise Distribution from Archive now creates a .pkg file instead of .ipa/.plist files.   This breaks our enterprise distribution system.  I haven't found any documentation on this change.  Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: When I export using Enterprise or In-House distribution on 6.0.1, I get ipa file. I didn't see the option anywhere to create the plist file now.

Comment: ok, now that is wierd.  I get a .pkg file every time.  I have not seen any new configuration item...is there one hidden somewhere?

Comment: More.  I have several archived enterprise apps that DO create a .ipa when Saved for Enterprise deployment.  Then I have a few that only create a .pkg (not an .ipa).   I haven't found any differences in configuration yet.  And they are all iphone/ipad targeted apps (not os-x).

Comment: I am same, I upgrade to xcode 6.0.1 use os8 , when built it create .pkg not create ipa. do you known supoport me

Comment: .pkg files are generally for Macintosh software distribution.  The .pkg ("Package") is for the Macintosh installer.  So a change like vualoaithu's will tell Xcode this is for iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add key "Application supports iTunes file sharing" value YES  or  "LSRequiresIPhoneOS" value YES to info.plist before choose Archive now.it will built ipa with xcode 6.0.1

Comment: "Application requires iPhone environment" (aka LSRequiresIPhoneOS) = YES was missing from the info.plist in the projects generating .pkg. Thanks!

Comment: But it doesn't allow to create a plist file when exporting IPA anyway. I mean for over the air distribution.